# Transformations and Isometries

Tags: geometry

> Suppose an isometry, $\alpha$, of the Euclidean plane $\Bbb R^2$ fixes different points $A$ and $B$, and does not fix a third point $C$. Describe $α$, with justication.

Since $\alpha$ fixes $A$ and $B$, $\alpha(A)=A$ and $\alpha(B)=B$, but not fix $C$, What is the relationship of these three … someone has hint? Thanks

Comment: What space are you working in? The Euclidean plane? Euclidean 3-space? Something else?

Comment: Also, you write $\alpha(A)$ and $\alpha(B)$, but you fail to put them into equations, so they don't say anything.

Comment: in Euclidean 2-space, R2

Comment: how to create equation

Comment: An equation consists of two things with an $=$ sign between them. What does it mean for a transformation to "fix" a point?

Comment: α(B)=B, and α(A)=A

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Go Greek! Draw the triangle $ABC$ and use a straightedge and compass.